# Redirect to custom contact form after product purchase

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

In wordpress, there is a plugin called woocommerce, were it enables the site to start selling a wide variety of products.

I have a `woocommerce` shop set up, but I would need to increase its functionality by adding a contact form right after a purchase has been made.

The chain of events would be:

1. Customer purchases product
2. Right after that, page redirects to a form for the user to fill (contains relevant information for me to work on)
3. Customer send the form and proceeds as normal.

I have this code to be placed into the theme code, but don't seem to find where:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woocommerce_redirect_after_checkout' );


function woocommerce_redirect_after_checkout() {

global $wp;



if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {



$redirect_url = 'https://businesscard.com/questionnaire/';



wp_redirect($redirect_url );



exit;

}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your Child Theme functionality using functions.php file can be located at:

```
wp-content/themes/your-child-theme/
```